# c/c++ vscode formatter closing braces on same indentation level as statements

Tags: c++, vscode-extensions, formatter, linter

General C/C++ code looks like this

```
{
    statement;
}
```

I want to format it in a slightly unorthodox way as follows,

```
{
    statement;
    }
    ^^ --> Closing braces on same indentation level as statements
```

How do I achieve this automatically in vscode?

[Precedence: Ratliff_style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Ratliff_style)

I dont see vscode formatter settings to control end brace behavior.